# Proving that $|A\times B| = |N\times N|$ when $A,B$ countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $|A| = |B| = |N|$.
Prove that $|A\times B| = $|N\times N|$.

What I have tried:

We know that $A,B$ are countable, because their cardinality is $|N|$.

Let
$A=\{a_i\mid i\in N\}$, $B=\{b_j\mid j\in N\}$, and $C=\{(a_i,b_j)\mid i,j \in N\}$.

Let $f\colon\{(i,j)\mid i,j \in N\}\to N\times N$ such that
 $$f(i,j)=(i,j)$$
The function is one to one and onto and therefore a bijection.
We showed that there exists a bijection and therefore the equation holds $|A\times B| = |N\times N|$.

Did I get it right?

Comment: I know that $N$ should be $\mathbb N$, yes. But it's so irrelevant to the actual proposition and its proof that I felt bad making this edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are mapping $f :C \rightarrow \mathbb{N \times N}$. Then, it seems ok, where $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_j\}$ are coming from the bijection between $A$ (resp. $B$) and $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Can I map directly from C to $N\times$N?
It is not given that $A,B\subseteq$N

Comment: you can send $(a_i,b_j)$ to $(i,j)$

Comment: Why is it essential?

Comment: Pardon. Can you please explain your doubt?

Comment: What you have proven here is saying that there is a bijection from $\mathbb{N \times N}$ to itself and the function is the identity map here. That doesn't conclude what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your assumption of countability is entirely irrelevant. What you show here is that if $A$ is in bijection with $X$ and $B$ is in bijection with $Y$, then $A\times B$ is in bijection with $X\times Y$.

You only apply this to the case where $X=Y$, and restrict it to the case where it is a countable set.

Your proof outline is fine, but your function is just the identity function. Since neither $A$ nor $B$ are assumed to be the same as $N$, this is not a function from $A\times B$, which you denote by $C$, to $N\times N$.

Comment: Isn't it plain to see that the function is injective and surjective, since it's the identity function?

Comment: You're right. It is the identity function. Which means I misread your question and you did not provide a bijection between $A\times B$ and $N\times N$.

Comment: If so, then what would a proper mapping between A$\times$B and N$\times$N?

Comment: Well... think...

Comment: http://karagila.org/2015/how-to-solve-your-problems/